# Unable to start debugging -visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution where i have 8/9 projects.
everything was working good and suddenly, I started to get an error when I start to debug. and it says

```
Unable to start debugging.
```

If I close visual studio and run it again, it works in the first try.
and after that it stops working.

In the configuration manager it is set to "Any CPU".

I tried many thing with no luck. Is there any help??

this is how the error looks like..

[image]

Comment: What kind of project(s) are you trying to debug?

Answer (score 6):

I got similar error:
"Unable to start debugging. Check your debugger settings by opening 
project properties and navigation to 'Configuration properties --> Debugging"

I have solved it by setting :
Properties--> Debugging --> Working Directory 
to $(ProjectDir)

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcw4dzyf.aspx), leaving the Working Directory setting blank is the same thing as setting it to $(ProjectDir).  But, if I leave Working Directory blank, I have issues.  When I set it to $(ProjectDir) or some other value, it works as expected.  I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Still the same solution required on Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

As it's an MVC web application, there's a couple of things to check. Firstly, are you sure the web project is set as your startup (this catches me and a couple of others in my office out from time to time)?

Secondly, where are you hosting the project? Are you using Cassini, or are you hosting it in IIS while you debug? If so, check IIS and make sure that the site is started, there's no issues with the AppPool, etc.

Finally, one way to try is to actually press Ctrl+F5 to run without the debugger attached, I often find that IE will then actually display an error that's causing the issue.

Comment: well, i tried the first one..didn't help and I am running locally..VS web development server.

Comment: Did you try running without the debugger attached to see if you get an error page in the browser?